# Freeswitch 1.10 on CentOS 7: Error while starting the server and no user registration

Tags: ipv6, freeswitch, sofia-sip

We used to have FS 1.4 working on CentOS 6. But that server had to be migrated to CentOS 7. When we take Freeswitch 1.10 and try to run with default configuration, we get below error -

```
[ERR] sofia.c:3254 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external (sip:mod_sofia@<Our IP>:5080;maddr=<Our IP>;transport=udp,tcp)
The likely causes for this are:
1) Another application is already listening on the specified address.
2) The IP the profile is attempting to bind to is not local to this system.
2020-05-02 12:38:55.853768 [ERR] sofia.c:3244 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]:5080;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 3 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
2020-05-02 12:38:55.853768 [ERR] sofia.c:3254 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]:5080;transport=udp,tcp)
The likely causes for this are:
1) Another application is already listening on the specified address.
2) The IP the profile is attempting to bind to is not local to this system.
2020-05-02 12:38:55.853768 [ERR] sofia.c:3244 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: internal-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]:5060;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 3 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
```

We have 19 dummy profiles available as part of default installation. In one of them, we added this cidr -
 and got this log entry while FS started -

```
2020-05-02 12:45:38.200896 [NOTICE] switch_utils.c:648 Adding 192.0.2.0/24 (allow) [1001@<Our IP>] to list domains
```

At the prompt, when we type "show registrations" it shows "0 total".

event_socket.conf.xml

```
<configuration name="event_socket.conf" description="Socket Client">
  <settings>
    <param name="nat-map" value="false"/>
    <param name="listen-ip" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <param name="listen-port" value="8021"/>
    <param name="password" value="ClueCon"/>
    <param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="loopnet.auto"/>
    <!--<param name="stop-on-bind-error" value="true"/>-->
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

In this link, we found this note but not sure how to apply it.

```
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_event_socket
"As of 1.6 you must supply an ACL. In order to allow all IPs you can use any_v4.auto in event_socket.conf.xml"
```

we did the installation referring to this page and built from source

```
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CentOS+7+and+RHEL+7#CentOS7andRHEL7-CentOS7andRHEL7-Stable
```

Appreciate your help very much. If you let me know what additional log information/config information you need, I shall update here.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve this issue. Providing details here in case it helps anyone.

Installation done as per this link (and built from Source)
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CentOS+7+and+RHEL+7#CentOS7andRHEL7-CentOS7andRHEL7-Stable

### Status before fix

When I ran "sofia status" in fs_cli, I got only the external profile loaded. If I tried "sofia profile internal reload", it was showing "Invalid profile".

### Changes to sip_profiles\internal.xml

On comparing internal.xml with the saved FS 1.4 version, I found these two differences -

### internal.xml (FS 1.4)

```
<!--<param name="ws-binding"  value=":5066"/> -->
<!--<param name="wss-binding" value=":7443"/>-->
```

### internal.xml (FS 1.10)

```
<param name="ws-binding"  value=":5066"/>
<param name="wss-binding" value=":7443"/>
```

On commenting above two lines and restarting Freeswitch, I found that internal profile was also loaded (shown by "sofia status"), Freeswitch was listening on port 5060, users could register and make calls. 
I am not familiar with purpose of those two lines, need to find out.